# How can I write XML from PowerPoint VBA?

Tags: xml, vba, powerpoint, add-in, msxml

I have another question. I need to develop a PowerPoint add-in (for 2003 and 2007 versions) that will be installed on some users computers. It needs to track some of the things they do when they give presentations and then send me the results. These will be on people's computers that are not under adminstration control (e.g. vendors and other external people). The only thing I will know for sure about their computers is that they will have PowerPoint. I think XML must be the easiest, MSXML I belive, but that is a reference dll. Is there anyway to know which version PowerPoint ships with so that I will always be sure that someone has this on their computer?

Answer (score 0):

Did some checking. Looks like it is version 5 that is in both PowerPoint 2003 and PowerPoint 2007. You can find it here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/269238